# text overflowing in css slider

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am facing problem in designing a review/feedback box.

Css-

```
.wellwhite
{
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 75%;
    padding: 24px;
    margin-top: 35px;
    background-color: #fff;
    border: 2px solid #fff;
    min-width: 269px;
    position: relative;
}
.well-review
{
    padding: 24px;
    border: 1px solid #efefef;
    background: #efefef;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px 1px #ccc;
    position:relative;
}
.slide-feedback
{
    position:relative;
}
.slide-feedback a
{
    position:absolute;

}
```

**Script**

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        $(function () {
            $('.slide-feedback a').hide();
            $('.slide-feedback a:first-child').show();
            setInterval(function () {
                $('.slide-feedback a:first-child').fadeOut(function () {
                    $(this).appendTo('.slide-feedback');
                }).next().show();
            }, 3000);


        });

</script>
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/stackmanoz/9hE5Y/)

Problem seemed so simple to me but couldn't get a solution yet. I get content overflows from the boundary class.

**Note-**

I don't want to use `overflow:hidden` because review would be varying according to user's feedback.

Comment: Add [`overflow: hidden;`](http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/9hE5Y/1/) -- or else be more thorough in your explanation as to what the problem actually is.

Comment: @Blazemonger, No I don't want to hide overflown contents. It is just it is not coming in bounded class.

Comment: What isn't coming? What's a "bounded class"? Please be specific and detailed as to what you want and what's wrong. I understand English might not be your first language, but I can't help you without a clear explanation.

Comment: `.well-review` is the boundary class in card-view shape. I want content comes in card shaped.

Answer (score 1):

The active `.slide-feedback a` is given `position: absolute;` in the CSS... which causes it to overflow rather than expand the parent div.

Solution: http://jsfiddle.net/9hE5Y/4/

```
.slide-feedback a
{
    position:static;

}
```

Comment: You might have to set the height of the slider card manually, because the varying length of the links inside. You need to set it high enough to contain the longest link in the list.

Comment: There is a brief moment where both the new item, and the old item are visible and given `display: inline;`, this accounts for the flicker... you might need to revise your jQuery to make the previous item immediately receive `display: none;` rather than that being applied after the new slide comes in.

Answer (score 0):

Try using overflow:hidden; on the box? Overflow can be set to auto, scroll or hidden. Can also use overflow-y for just vertical overflow control.

Comment: No I don't want to hide overflown contents. It is just it is not coming in bounded class.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `position: absolute;` on `.slide-feedback a`